# Calculation of 12000 Lunar Orbits/Earth Day

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, earth, speed, distance

I am really interested in the calculation of the following speed value in meter-per-second unit:

Speed of something that is able to travel in one earth day the distance that it would take for the moon to orbit the earth 12000 times.

Some people have calculated this using Einstein' theory but I am not mastering this so I resort to you to see if some scientist is able to calculate this.

Comment: Indeed this is an interesting question, though was misunderstood. What @charfeddine.ahmed was curiosity to know if the guy who did comparison between speed of light and "12000 Lunar Orbits/Earth Day" was following scientific and mathematical laws and figures or just played around with figures and numbers in order to finalize his trick. Even though this is definitely sort of pseudoscience, but it is still a challenge for us to review the calculations and methods done on http://www.speed-light.info/speed_of_light_12000.htm and highlight any mathematical or physical fallacies if used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lots of people can.  This is because there is nothing to calculate.  Without a spec for the desired units of the answer it can be as simple as "12000 lunar orbits/day".

If you do want to convert this to other units, then you have to provide a clear definition of this unit of length you are calling a "lunar orbit", of course.  Without that, nobody can do the calculation to get the speed into other unrelated units.

Comment: You say that there is nothing to calculate, but in the following link I see many complex calculus leading to the conclusion that this value amounts to the speed of light:
http://www.speed-light.info/speed_of_light_12000.htm
I wanted to verify that others will reach some result.

Comment: @charf: Read what I wrote. There is nothing to calculate since you didn't specify what units the result should be in, so your question already contains its own answer. Your very poorly written question is the problem in several ways: 1 - Asking if "someone can" is actually off topic here. 2 - Without a spec of output units there is nothing to calculate. 3 - You haven't defined how exactly a "lunar orbit" is measured (there a lots of ways) for someone that did want to convert your value to unrelated units, like meters/second.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will try rephrase the question in better way.

Comment: @charfeddine.ahmed: That is a crackpot link.    And there's no "complex calculus" in it.

Comment: Well if I don't know the theory of relativity then I am not able to make such claim. When I looked at the link I was intuitively believing it. So now I want to clear this out with scientific proof.

Comment: @ Dimensio1n0: In your opinion, mine, and everyone's interested in real science - yes, it is a crackpot link. However; if you knew that this guy received a Master's degree (and perhaps even the Doctorate) because of such cheats, then you may excuse charfeddine for his question and try to clarify things differently.